# Como fazer resumo de um texto longo usando o Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, aplicação-web, jsp, jstl, thymeleaf

Tenho um objeto com dois atributos, um é o id e o outro é atributo do tipo strring  chamado texto
do tipo "TEXT" (banco postgres) que é usado para armazenar o texto
de uma postagem de um cliente.

Quando a aplicação carrega essas
postagens na pagina,para não ficar um texto muito extenso  eu gostaria de fazer um resumo desse texto.

Consegui  fazer isso usando o JSP, de forma fácil, usando o `forTokens`.

Como fazer o mesmo que o código abaixo usando 
o thymeleaf?

```
<p class="post-texto">
    <c:forTokens var="resumo" items="${p.texto}" delims=" " begin="0" end="60">
            ${resumo}
    </c:forTokens><a href="<c:url value="/${p.link}" />">[Continue lendo]</a>
</p>
```

Pesquisei mas não encontrei nada semelhante ao forTokens no thymeleaf.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função `abbreviate` da expressão `#strings`. Por exemplo:

```
<p th:text="${#strings.abbreviate(resumo,5)} "></p>
```

Para mais detalhes sobre expressões segue o [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-3-expressions)